# Sqlite nested case query

Tags: sqlite, case

He I am trying to build sql query with multiple nested case querys.

My table has this columns: ID,UserId, EventInTime, InTime, EventOutTime, OutTime.

Here is pseudo code for column that troubles me:

```
(If EventInTime ==0 then IT = InTime else IT = EventInTime;
If EventOutTime ==0 then IT = OutTime else OT = EventOutTime;
If IT or OT ==0 then 0 else OT-IT) as Suma
```

Heres my code:

```
SELECT 
UserId, 
StatId, 
case when 
    case when EventInTime =0 
    then InTime 
    else EventInTime end=0 
    or 
        case when EventOutTime =0 
        then OutTime 
        else EventOutTime end 
        then 0
 else 
    case when EventOutTime =0 
    then OutTime 
    else EventOutTime end -
        case when EventInTime =0 
        then InTime 
        else EventInTime end 
        as suma
from Worktimes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The comparison against zero of the value of the second inner CASE is missing:

```
SELECT UserId,
       StatId,
       CASE
       WHEN CASE EventInTime
            WHEN 0 THEN InTime
                   ELSE EventInTime
            END = 0
            OR
            CASE EventOutTime
            WHEN 0 THEN OutTime
                   ELSE EventOutTime
            END = 0                    -- !!!
       THEN 0
       ELSE CASE EventOutTime
            WHEN 0 THEN OutTime
                   ELSE EventOutTime
            END
            -
            CASE EventInTime
            WHEN 0 THEN InTime
                   ELSE EventInTime
            END
       END AS Suma
FROM Worktimes;
```

IT and OT are zero only if both columns are zero, so the first two inner CASEs can be simplified:

```
SELECT UserId,
       StatId,
       CASE
       WHEN (InTime  = 0 AND EventInTime  = 0) OR
            (OutTime = 0 AND EventOutTime = 0)
       THEN 0
       ELSE CASE EventOutTime
            WHEN 0 THEN OutTime
                   ELSE EventOutTime
            END
            -
            CASE EventInTime
            WHEN 0 THEN InTime
                   ELSE EventInTime
            END
       END AS Suma
FROM Worktimes;
```

Another way to make the query simpler would be to introduce `IT` and `OT` as virtual columns (this requires a separate subquery):

```
SELECT UserId,
       StatId,
       CASE WHEN IT = 0 OR OT = 0
            THEN 0
            ELSE OT - IT
       END AS Suma
FROM (SELECT UserId,
             StatId,
             CASE EventInTime
                  WHEN 0 THEN InTime
                  ELSE EventInTime
             END AS IT,
             CASE EventOutTime
                  WHEN 0 THEN OutTime
                  ELSE EventOutTime
             END AS OT
      FROM Worktimes);
```